# Can the President of the United States spend private funds on official events in the White House?

Tags: united-states, president

Couple of days ago, Trump [spent lots of money](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/8195963/donald-trump-mcdonalds-fast-food-clemson-tigers-white-house-caterers-shut-down/), paying from his own private funds, on hosting a football team in the White House for an official event.

Assuming the event was official, i.e. not made privately for/by Trump, isn't there any policy against the president spending private funds to host such event? If so, how did Trump bypass it?

Comment: For what reason would that be illegal?  Many on the left complain that he doesn't pay enough taxes.  Now you seem to be complaining that he used his own money for a government function?

Comment: @James dunno it doesn't sound right for me. Not really illegal, just not... Right

Answer (score 12):

Presidents have to pay for various personal expenses incurred during their stay in the White House. Only meals [for state functions](http://mentalfloss.com/article/20681/who-pays-obama-familys-food) that are [prepared by White House chefs are paid for by the government](https://www.theguardian.com/money/us-money-blog/2014/nov/28/obama-bill-white-house-thanksgiving).

> ... when his family and personal guests eat what's coming out of the kitchen, he'll have to foot the bill himself. Luckily for him, though, the government picks up the tab if he's having a state function at the White House, which could get pricey since the White House's website touts that its five chefs can crank out dinner for 140 or hors d'oeuvres for over a thousand people.

Since the meals weren't prepared by the White House, the President can choose to foot the bill. **There aren't any rules preventing Presidents from spending their own money on White House functions.**

In general, Presidents also have to pay for groceries and [other personal necessities](https://www.tweentribune.com/article/tween56/white-house-obama-pays-his-toothpaste/).